# Get approximate upper bound of 12 bit numbers

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, boolean-algebra

I have 8 12 bit unsigned numbers. I want to compute an approximate upper bound(`b` such that all numbers are less than this number) of these numbers with minimum combinational logic(which can run at fastest clock without pipeline). I can bitwise OR all of them to get a rough estimate(Worst case 100% off). Is there a better way? A solution between `d0` and `e0`

```
module get_max
(

);


  wire [11:0] a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7;
  wire [11:0] b0,b1,b2,b3;
  wire [11:0] c0,c1;
  wire [11:0] d0;
  wire [11:0] e0;

  assign b0 = ((a0 > a1) ? a0 : a1);
  assign b1 = ((a2 > a3) ? a2 : a3);
  assign b2 = ((a4 > a5) ? a4 : a5);
  assign b3 = ((a6 > a7) ? a6 : a7);

  assign c0 = ((b0 > b1) ? b0 : b1);
  assign c1 = ((b2 > b3) ? b2 : b3);

  assign d0 = ((c0 > c1) ? c0 : c1);

  assign e0 = a0|a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|a6|a7;



endmodule
```

Comment: Magnitude compare the 4 MSBs (or 6 or 8 according to accuracy/resources) and OR the remaining LSBs. (assuming unsigned of course)

Comment: When you say minimum logic, are you referring to minimum depth, or minimum number of gates, or what?

Comment: An interesting question.

Comment: There are different approaches to this. For example, one could have an 8-bit, 8 input module that calls a 7-bit, 8-input module if all have their upper bits set or clear, but otherwise selectively calls various 7-bit, N-M-input modules for remaining cases. Etc. "all the way down." Other pipelined ideas are crossing my mind. I'll have to agree the question is interesting. But there must already be papers on this. I assume these values are in their own registers where every bit is available in parallel. But perhaps that's not the case? Anyway, +1 just because I'd like to see a creative answer.

Comment: So, the `d0` solution is the best possible answer, while the `e0` solution is arguably the cheapest possible correct answer in terms of combinatorial logic (other than just using "all ones", obviously). In order to find a "more optimum" solution -- one that gives a better answer than `e0`, but doesn't cost as much as `d0` -- we'd have to know how to quantify "a better answer" (in terms of what that would mean in your application) and how to trade that off against complexity.

Comment: This is way too unconstrained, a completely *free* solution is to just always output 2**12-1. There's no best solution without relevant metrics.

Comment: @Hearth Design which can run at fastest clock without pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

The general way to do this is with something called a comparator tree. You can use a comparator tree to pick either the largest value or the smallest value. The simplest comparator tree is just a tree of magnitude comparisons between pairs of values, selecting the result with log2 levels. But each comparator is implemented as a subtractor and hence has a rather large critical path. It's possible to build an alternative structure which improves on the critical path significantly. See http://archvlsi.ics.forth.gr/muqpro/cmpTree.html for one such technique.

Comment: What do you think the OP's `d0` solution is?

Comment: A comparator tree. Knowing the proper term can be half the battle. You're going to down vote me for not explicitly spelling out that this is what op has built, and providing a link to a master's thesis that describes more efficient ways of building comparator trees?

Comment: The downvote is for not answering the actual question, which is about alternative solutions, not how to build the solutions he already has.

Comment: OP has commented that they're interested in the fastest clock with the least pipeline, so a more efficient comparator tree could also be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Best is clearly in the eye of the beholder, and I don't know what constraints you have.

Another option is serial - treat each 12 bit register as a shift register and clock  the bits into a logic unit (LU), MSB first.  The output is a 1 if any of the inputs are 1, and this sets the corresponding bit in the output register.  Where this is different to the ORing of all individual bits is that each time the LU outputs a 1, any input that has the current bit a 0 is ignored in the future (possibly implemented by clearing the corresponding register).

This would seem to have low requirements on logic, but possibly high on cycles.